# Save Lxterminal session with named tabs

Tags: terminal, lxterminal

There is a possibility to create named tabs in `lxterminal`.

I got an idea to create a few tabs named like `basic`, `coding`, `scripting`,
`administration`.

Is there a way to save it as something like a session and after I close
lxterminal, I would have the possibility to open these four tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Configure named tabs with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

lxterminal --tabs=basic,coding,scripting,administration
```